# Using Remote Method Invocation to interact with windows service? Better alternatives?

Tags: service, rmi, interactive

I am currently using Remote Method Invocation to interact with a windows service. As services cannot be interactive (UI) strictly from Vista and above, I cannot directly call those methods. So I am using Remote Method Invocation to access those methods. How safe is RMI?

Are there any better alternatives to using RMI? Like File channeling/ sockets and Listeners.

edit: Let me make it clear,

I have a java application which runs as a windows service. But I would like to manipulate the service and the way it works from an user interface but When I try to do that, Windows wont allow me to do that. So I am using RMI to manipulate the windows service from an user interface.(interactively).

Comment: What does not having a UI have to do with being able to call them via RMI?

Comment: I have a java application which runs as a windows service. But I would like to manipulate the service and the way it works from an user interface but When I try to do that, Windows wont allow me to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there is a reason for windows services not being able to have an UI. If you need an UI to interact with the service, what's the reason for running the program to interact with as a service anyway?

That being said, I'm using RMI to interact with the service (simply to do some configuration, poll status information; the program being executed as a service usually runs without any user interaction) - it's worked out pretty well so far.

You could of course use simple sockets (however, RMI is also built on sockets). A simple Listener won't work since you'll need some inter process communication.